# Помогите разобраться, если юзер воводит не число, нужно что бы выполнялась проверка, и программа просила ввести число повторно

Tags: javascript

Прошу не судить строго, я новичок, не могу понять что делать, что бы сделать проверку. Понимаю что надо делать циклом и подключать isNaN

```
    function getMinimalNumber (a,b,c,d) {
    if (a < b && a < c && a < d) {
    return a; 
   }
    else if (b < a && b < c && b < d) {
     return b; 
   } 
    else if (c < a && c < b && c < d) {
    return c;
  }
    else {
    return d;
  }
  }

  var a = prompt ('Enter the number:');

  var b = prompt ('Enter the next number:');

  var c = prompt ('Enter the before last number:');

  var d = prompt ('Enter the last number:');

  function isNumberValid (text)
```

Comment: Если ответ ниже верный - приймите его, нажав на галочку.

Answer (score 1):

К примеру:

```js
let a;
while(true) {
  a=prompt('enter a number:');
  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(a))&&isFinite(a)) break;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.